# Possible to use multi-line text in the designer for string aura:attribute or even rich-text attributes?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, app-builder, design-attributes

I have components which need complex parametrization like JSON values, richtext or very long text values.

My attribute is defined as string  like this

```
<aura:attribute name="pageParams" type="String" default="" access="global" />
```

and in the design

```
<design:attribute name="pageParams" label="Custom Parameters"   description="..." />
```

Now in the designer I get only tiny one-line inputs looking like

[image]

Is there any way to get multiline textareas or Richtext-inputs inside the designer (Lightning App Builder)?

Anything planned or on the roadmap?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for **design:attribute**, looks like what you are looking for is not supported at the time being.

> For Lightning page interfaces, the design resource supports only attributes of type Integer, String, or Boolean.

More details on the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm).